# Geoserver/geotools DB2 extension support

Tags: geoserver, geotools, extensions, db2

I'm evaluating the migration of a postgis/postgres database to a DB2 spatial db.
A Geoserver instance is connected to the postgis datasources, so I know there is an [extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/db2.html) available for making the same connections from Geoserver to the DB2 datasources.

I've been looking for an up-to-date page or documentation where I can find the supported versions of [DB2 or the DB2 drivers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) for each [gt-jdbc-db2](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/db2.html) release (the library behind the extension AFAIK), but I haven't been able to find any info about this.

In the end, what I need to know is the versions of DB2 supported by the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone gets in the same situation in the future, I discarded the option of migrating to DB2 after talking to the creator of the geoserver DB2 plugin.

As discussed [in the geoserver users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/36149744/), he does not recommend using DB2 spatial extender as it's not being maintained anymore, and he can't assure which versions of DB2 are supported by the extension.

So, the documentation I was looking for is not available at the moment, and apparently it won't be available in the (near) future neither as no-one is maintaining the extension.